# Checkbox not triggering event in jQuery PCP when skinned with jQuery iPhone-Style-Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, forms

I've built a form using HTML and jQuery. The form is designed to generate a quote on the fly for the user.

I would also like the checkboxes used to be styled using jQuery iPhone Style Checkboxes (iSC).

I've implemented jQuery Price Calculator Pro (PCP) as well as iSC. When iSC is not implemented the system works perfectly, however once iSC is implemented the change in price (seen in the top right) no longer triggers.

I assumed this was because the event was triggered by a .click, from what I can find this is not the case.

I have been able to implement the following which will allow me to add a line of code that triggers whatever it is that PCP needs in order to function:

```
$(window).load(function() {             

var onchange_checkbox = ($('#eCommerce')).iphoneStyle({
    onChange: function() { 
            if ($('#eCommerce').is(':checked')) {
                $('#eCommerce-Output').removeClass('dispnone');
                console.log('eCommerce is on');
        } 
            else { 
            $('#eCommerce-Output').addClass('dispnone');
            console.log('eCommerce is off');
            };
    }
});
```

As you will be able to see on the [live version of the page](http://bit.ly/TDVEOF) via the console -- the above triggers perfectly when the iPhone toggle is switched.

If you tick the unstyled checkbox at the top you will be able to see what I'm wanting the iPhone toggles to do. The relevant .js file for the calculation [can be found here](http://mtgconsulting.com.au/client-files/testing/form-assets/jquery-price-calculator-pro.js).

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't see an unstyled checkbox at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The price is updated every time a change event for one of the form inputs is triggered. So we need to trigger this event manually when the iphone style checkbox changes.

**Edit:** iPhone Style Checkboxes actually passes the checkbox element to the onChange function as the first parameter. The this keyword will not work as expected. I've updated my answer accordingly.

```
var onchange_checkbox = ($('#eCommerce')).iphoneStyle({
    onChange: function(input) { 
        input.trigger('change');
    }
});
```

I hope this helps!

Ben.

Comment: is there any way i could make this apply universally rather than having to put it in the code for each var?

Comment: Not that I am aware. In all honesty, the iPhone Style Checkboxes module should be doing this itself.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the widgetized DOM leads me to believe that the following should work :

```
$(function() {             
    var onchange_checkbox = ($('#eCommerce')).iphoneStyle({
        onChange: function() { 
            $(this).closest('.iPhoneCheckContainer').find('input').trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
```

If it works, this will be a general solution in that the 'onChange' handler :

- makes no assumptions about element ids
- works relative to the clicked widget to find the underlying input element (checkbox/radiobutton), from which the widget was made (and which still exists), and triggers its change event.